# Trouble with Windows 11 DLL during launching a installer

Tags: java, dll

I'm trying to install a specific product, however before the installation launcher start the configuration. a pop up shows an error with a DLL. This occurs on Windows 11.

The error shows as follows:

```
Flexeraaxd$aaa: Windows DLL failed to load at Flexeraaxd.af(Unknown Source) 
    at Flexeraaxd.aa(Unknown Source) 
    at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.init(Unknown Source) 
    at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.executeApplication(Unknown Source) at com.zerog.ia.installer.Main.main(Unknown Source) 
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) 
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) 
    at com.zerog.lax.LAX.launch(Unknown Source) 
    at com.zerog.lax.LAX.main(Unknown Source)
```

I have already JRE 1.8.0 installed, jdk-11.0.11. I have tried set the variable JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Dos.name=Windows 7", but it did not work.
I have tried to run the installer on compatibility mode (W8 / W7) without success.

Comment: were you able to find a work around for installing your specific product on win 11?

Please let me know if you were able to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing it to JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Dos.name=Windows 7"

Change it to JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Dos.name=Windows Server 2019"

Be sure to include the quotes